# different types of objects in std::vector or another data structure

Tags: c++, stl

I want to store such structure

```
  template <typename var_type> struct
  {
  int some_var;
  //...some antoher vars
  var_type problem_var;
  };
```

in vector or something like vector, how can i do that? I can't create vector with template content

Comment: "I can't create vector with template content" - why not? What happens if you name your struct, then write `std::vector<mystruct<float> >`? (replacing `mystruct` with the name you gave your struct, and `float` with the template argument you want to use).

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think what he is trying to say is that he wants a heterogeneous container.

Comment: maybe it is me, but the question is not terribly clear. Can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I think you're right, that just didn't occur to me until I saw Archie's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: Steve, thanks, but i can't use it, because there may be not only a float

Answer (score 5):

If you know the list of types up front, `boost::variant<>` can be more suitable than `boost::any`. In your case, you might need

```
typedef boost:variant<
   mystruct<float>,
   mystruct<int>
   mystruct<std::string>
> my_variant;
```

This will allow only these 3 types. Alternatively, you might want `mystruct<boost:variant<float, int, std::string> >`, which is superficially similar. I can't judge from your question which would be most suited to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a class hierarchy with the type of objects you need to store and always upcast to the base class when inserting into the vector?

The drawback is that you always have to know what type to downcast to when extracting items from the vector or using the base class interface (probably a getter method).